How to access Bybit API with google apps script
I'm trying to get any response from the Bybit API using google apps script. I have been able to get response from the API when using simple nodeJS code. But when converting the syntax to google apps script I get a strange 403 error.
I have tried multiple different syntax to make this work. After reading through countless documentation and looking how other people get responses from API's using app script, I have code that should work but doesn't, I feel stuck now.
This is my current Google Apps Script code, I have changed the values of apiKey and secret for this:

var apiKey = 'XXXXX';
var timestamp = new Date().getTime().toString();
var recvWindow = '5000';
var parameters = 'accountType=SPOT';

var message = timestamp + apiKey + recvWindow + parameters;
var url = 'https://api.bybit.com/v5/asset/transfer/query-account-coins-balance?accountType=SPOT';

const secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX';

function createSign() {

var signatureBytes = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(message, secret);
var signature = signatureBytes.reduce(function(str, byte) {
return str + ('0' + (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2);
}, '');

Logger.log(signature);
return signature.toString();
}

function main() {

var config = {
method: 'GET',
headers: {
'X-BAPI-API-KEY': apiKey,
'X-BAPI-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
'X-BAPI-RECV-WINDOW': recvWindow,
'X-BAPI-SIGN': createSign()
},
muteHttpExceptions: true
}

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, config);
var response2 = UrlFetchApp.getRequest(url, config);
Logger.log(response2);
Logger.log(response);
}


And this is what I get:

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>403 ERROR</H1>
<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
<HR noshade size="1px">
The Amazon CloudFront distribution is configured to block access from your country.
We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
<BR clear="all">
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
<BR clear="all">
<HR noshade size="1px">
<PRE>
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: ns9XoZU762a7V7mCAE07rgmK3dWkOtjKK9LHuyNjyTW14CQkdvUGtw==
</PRE>
<ADDRESS>
</ADDRESS>
</BODY></HTML>



This is the node.js code that works fine:

const axios = require('axios');
const crypto = require('crypto');

const apiKey = 'XXXXXXX';
const timestamp = Date.now().toString();
const recvWindow = '5000';

const secret = 'XXXXXXXXX'

function sign(parameters, secret) {
    const signature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret).update(timestamp + apiKey + recvWindow + parameters).digest('hex');
    console.log(signature);
    return signature.toString();
}

async function main() {

    const config = {
        method: 'get',
        url: 'https://api.bybit.com/v5/asset/transfer/query-account-coins-balance?accountType=SPOT',
        headers: { 
          'X-BAPI-API-KEY': apiKey, 
          'X-BAPI-TIMESTAMP': timestamp, 
          'X-BAPI-RECV-WINDOW': recvWindow, 
          'X-BAPI-SIGN': sign('accountType=SPOT', secret)
        }
      };
      
     await axios(config)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data.result);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });

  console.log(sign('accountType=SPOT', secret).length);
}

main();



About I have been able to get response from the API when using simple nodeJS code., can you provide your script of Node.js?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Hello @Tanaike I have now added the node.js code that works.

Thank you for replying. When I saw your added Node.js script, I thought that the HTTP request of your Google Apps Script was the same as that of the Node.js. From your error message, I'm worried about The Amazon CloudFront distribution is configured to block access from your country.. In this case, how about asking your situation to the administrator of the API?
